# In House MD Babies & Bushwater why did Vogel cancel the c-section?

Tags: house

I get that he did not want her in clinical trial and wanted to get on House, but risking patients life to do it? Wouldn't he be reliable in lawsuit against hospital for her death?

Wouldn't better choice be to let her go through but then deny her entry to study?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from messing with House, Vogler canceled the procedure to ensure the drug trial that House was trying to get her into was not affected by the high risk of the female patient causing a negative result in the drug trial.

> House: So she kicks off, his numbers look bad
>
> Vogler: The numbers look bad, the study looks bad
>
> House: Which would cost you money
>
> Vogler: Yeah, and keep a life-saving protocol off the market
>
> House: One person, one blip in the data
>
> .....
>
> Vogler: One person should never endanger the lives of 1000's

Source: House M.D., Season 1 Episode 18, around 29m30s

If the C-Section had gone ahead (a must-do before the experimental drug could be administered) THEN she were rejected access to the trial, I'd say that would leave the hospital more open to liability - tricking her into a C-Section she never really wanted in the first place so the doctors could do as they please.